# node error while loading shared libraries libnode.so.72

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu (linux), somehow i get the following error on each instruction executed in my terminal:

`node: error while loading shared libraries: libnode.so.72: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 11):

I found many answers, but the following `apt install` fix it easily:

`sudo apt install libnode72`

Comment: For me worked: sudo apt install libnode108